# how to make a text parsing function efficient in R

Tags: r, text-processing, text-parsing

I have this function which calculates the consonanceScore of a book. First I import the phonetics dictionary [from CMU](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/cmusphinx/code/trunk/cmudict/cmudict-0.7b) (which forms a dataframe of about 134000 rows and 33 column variables; any row in the CMUdictionary is basically of the form CLOUDS  K L AW1 D Z. The first column has the words, and the remaining columns have their phonetic equivalents). After getting the CMU dictionary, I parse a book into a vector containing all the words; max-length of any one book (so far): 218711 . Each word's phonetics are compared with the phonetics in the consecutive word, and the consecutive+1 word. The TRUE match values are then combined into a sum. The function I have is this:

```
getConsonanceScore <- function(book, consonanceScore, CMUdict) {

  for (i in 1:((length(book)) - 2)) {

    index1 <- replaceIfEmpty(which (toupper(book[i]) == CMUdict[,1]))
    index2 <- replaceIfEmpty(which (toupper(book[i + 1]) == CMUdict[,1]))
    index3 <- replaceIfEmpty(which (toupper(book[i + 2]) == CMUdict[,1]))

    word1 <- as.character(CMUdict[index1, which(CMUdict[index1,] != "")])
    word2 <- as.character(CMUdict[index2, which(CMUdict[index2,] != "")])
    word3 <- as.character(CMUdict[index3, which(CMUdict[index3,] != "")])

    consonanceScore <- sum(word1 %in% word2)
    consonanceScore <- consonanceScore + sum(word1 %in% word3)
    consonanceScore <- consonanceScore / length(book)
  }

  return(consonanceScore)
}
```

A replaceIfEmpty function basically just returns the index for a dummy value (that has been declared in the last row of the dataframe) if there is no match found in the CMU dictionary for any word in the book. It goes like this:

```
replaceIfEmpty <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) > 0)
  {
    return (x)
  }
  else
  {
    x = 133780
  return(x)
  }
}
```

The issue that I am facing is that getConsonanceScore function takes **a lot** of time. So much so that in the loop, I had to divide the book length by 1000 just to check if the function was working alright. I am new to R, and would really be grateful for some help on making this function more efficient and consume less time, are there any ways of doing this? (I have to later call this function on possibly 50-100 books) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Am I right that you try to find words with the same pronounciation and with the distance between them <=2 ? if so, why keep all the sounds in different columns? you can concatenate them together and compare character strings. You'll get a `data.frame` with only two columns: spelling and pronounciation, then you can treat second column as a vector and do necessary comparisons quite simply.

Comment: Yes, true. But basically what I am trying to do is to compare each individual sound component in one word with each individual sound component in another word. For example, if there were two words sun and sky in close succession then only their 's' sound would match. So, should I treat them separately then? Is their a way where two character strings can be compared, and somehow I get the similarity of their individual components? My guess is that a normal '==' would compare the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-read recently your question, comments and @wibeasley's answer and got that didn't understand everything correctly. Now it have become more clear, and I'll try to suggest something useful.

First of all, we need a small example to work with. I've made it from the dictionary in your link.

```
dictdf <- read.table(text =
"A  AH0
CALLED  K AO1 L D
DOG  D AO1 G
DOGMA  D AA1 G M AH0
HAVE  HH AE1 V
I  AY1", 
header = F, col.names = paste0("V", 1:25), fill = T, stringsAsFactors = F )

#       V1  V2  V3 V4 V5  V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
# 1      A AH0               NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 2 CALLED   K AO1  L  D     NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 3    DOG   D AO1  G        NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 4  DOGMA   D AA1  G  M AH0 NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 5   HAVE  HH AE1  V        NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 6      I AY1               NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

bookdf <- data.frame(words = c("I", "have", "a", "dog", "called", "Dogma"))

#    words
# 1      I
# 2   have
# 3      a
# 4    dog
# 5 called
# 6  Dogma
```

Here we read data from dictionary with `fill = T` and manually define number of columns in `data.frame` by setting `col.names`. You may make 50, 100 or some other number of columns (but I don't think there are so long words in the dictionary). And we make a `bookdf` - a vector of words in the form of `data.frame`.

Then let's merge book and dictionary together. I use `dplyr` library mentioned by @wibeasley.

```
# for big data frames dplyr does merging fast
require("dplyr")

# make all letters uppercase 
bookdf[,1] <- toupper(bookdf[,1])
# merge
bookphon <- left_join(bookdf, dictdf, by = c("words" = "V1"))

#    words  V2  V3 V4 V5  V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
# 1      I AY1               NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 2   HAVE  HH AE1  V        NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 3      A AH0               NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 4    DOG   D AO1  G        NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 5 CALLED   K AO1  L  D     NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 6  DOGMA   D AA1  G  M AH0 NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

And after that we scan rowwise for matching sounds in consecutive words. I arranged it with the help of sapply.

```
consonanceScore <- 
  sapply(1:(nrow(bookphon)-2), 
         conScore <- function(i_row)
         {
           word1 <- bookphon[i_row,][,-1]
           word2 <- bookphon[i_row+1,][,-1]
           word3 <- bookphon[i_row+2,][,-1]

           word1 <- unlist( word1[which(!is.na(word1) & word1 != "")] )
           word2 <- unlist( word2[which(!is.na(word2) & word2 != "")] )
           word3 <- unlist( word3[which(!is.na(word3) & word3 != "")] )

           sum(word1 %in% word2) + sum(word1 %in% word3)
         })

[1] 0 0 0 4
```

There are no same phonemes in first three rows but the 4-th word 'dog' has 2 matching sounds with 'called' (D and O/A) and 2 matches with 'dogma' (D and G). The result is a numeric vector, you can `sum()` it, divide by `nrow(bookdf)` or whatever you need.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I have been trying to implement what @wibeasley proposed, but was stuck in the use of sapply, you have made it seem quite easy. I created another sort of slightly different function which when implemented in a for loop instead of sapply took about 15 minutes for one book, which even though quite an enormous betterment than before, wasn't as fast as I hope to achieve. I am going to try to work with yours and then post the final code for any further advice from you guys. Thank you, I am quite grateful that you wrote the entire code.

Comment: I like it, @inscaven. 3 ideas that may not pan out.  (1a) In `bookphon`, replace zero-length words with `NA` to eliminate the inner-loop comparisons like `word1 != ""`.  (Maybe with `dplyr::mutate_each()`. (1b) Is there a way to eliminate `!is.na(word1)` also? (For instance, if `NA`s are ignored in a later comparison.) (2) I don't know if it will be faster (or even correct), but consider if there's a way to vectorize across the three words, maybe something like `word <- bookphon[i_row+0:2,][,-1]` and the second block too. (3) Drop the first column before `sapply`, so you can drop the `[,-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's working correctly?  Isn't that function returning `consonanceScore` just for the last three words of the book?  If the loop's 3rd-to-last-line is

```
consonanceScore <- sum(word1 %in% word2)
```

, how is its value being recorded, or influencing later iterations of the loop?

There are several vectorization approaches that will increase your speed, but for something tricky like this, I like making sure the slow loopy way is working correctly first.  While you're in that stage of development, here are some suggestions how to make the code quicker and/or neater (which hopefully helps you debug with more clarity).

**Short-term suggestions**

- Inside `replaceIfEmpty()`, use `ifelse()`.  Maybe even use `ifelse()` directly inside the main function.
- Why is `as.character()` necessary?  That casting can be expensive.  Are those columns `factor`s?  If so, use `, stringsAsFactors=F` when you use something like `read.csv()`.
- Don't use `toupper()` three times for each iteration.  Just convert the whole thing once before the loop starts.
- Similarly, don't execute `/ length(book)` for each iteration.  Since it's the same denominator for the whole book, divide the final vector of numerators only once (after the loop's done).

**Long-term suggestions**

- Eventually I think you'll want to lookup each word only once, instead of three times.  Those lookups are expensive.  Similar to @inscaven 's suggestion, I think an intermediate table make sense (where each row is a book's word).
- To produce the intermediate table, you should get much better performance from a join function written and optimized by someone else in C/C++.  Consider something like `dplyr::left_join()`.  Maybe `book` has to be converted to a single-variable `data.frame` first.  Then *left* join it to the first column of the dictionary.  The row's subsequent columns will essentially be appended to the right side of `book` (which I think is what's happening now).
- Once each iteration is quicker and correct, consider using one of the *x*apply functions, or something in `dplyr`.  The advantage of these functions is that memory for the entire vector isn't destroyed and reallocated for every single word in each book.

Comment: Thank you lots, I've been trying to understand the left_join method, and was very much impressed what it can do, have also accommodated all the other points you mention. Am going to work with what inscaven posted , and compare efficiencies, and will post the code for further advice. Thanks very much again! The book that I parsed thanks to the left_join method took about 15minutes for consonanceScore. Was greatly impressed with that, even though have to try to make it more efficient. Will post code for further pointers!

Comment: No problem. This was a fun question.  If you don't mind at the end, tell us a rough estimate how long each draft (of the algorithm) takes for one book.  ...just something to update my prior probabilities during future coding.

Comment: Sure! The 15m that I said earlier was for just comparing the consecutive words, and not every other. I tried wibeasly method, it took about 30-40 minutes, and mine I am still testing. I am using something like this at the moment:  ' consonanceScore <- sapply(1: (nrow(bookP) - 2), 
                            conscore <- function(i_row) {
                              sum(match(bookP[i_row,], bookP[i_row + 1,], incomparables = NA, nomatch = 0) > 0, na.rm = TRUE) +
   sum(match(bookP[i_row,], bookP[i_row + 2,], incomparables = NA, nomatch = 0) > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
     })' what do you think?

Comment: Sorry for getting to it late. I just tested the time, and it comes to 37.63815 secs for a book of 3281 words. I tested my method too, and it does it in a time of 21.53423 secs. However, the values are different. inscaven's method gives 0.6690034 while mine gives 0.6799756. I can't figure out why that is when they seem to be doing the same thing.

Comment: Assuming neither has a true mistake, my first guess about the 1.5% discrepancy is that it's due to differences/inaccuracies of finite precision arithmetic.  Temporarily remove the division, and see if the sums are the same for the two versions.  Pick a small enough book that the sum is less than roughly 10^10.  If they *don't* match in this scenario, I'd start suspecting an error in one of them.  If the *do* match, then favor the one that uses division less (assuming the sum of each book doesn't overflowing the integer part of the floating numeric).  Consider sharing these in a github gist.

Comment: I figured out why they are different! I think its because inscaven is not comparing the actual words, their code goes like: bookphon[i_row,][,-1] where the first column is being dropped. So if bookphon[5] was like Word phonetic1 phonetic2, then the word 'Word' is being dropped, which is the correct way. Whereas mine was comparing whole words as well. I figured that once divided by the length of the book, the error would carry across for all books, and so proportion might be the same. The results are identical once I change my code to include that.

Comment: And now inscaven's time = 6.589377 secs and mine = 5.886337 secs. Do you think on gist so that others might find it useful? Or just so that one could see the whole code and results?

Comment: Both?  I'm interested, and I'm losing track of the current state of both versions.  Don't feel obligated though.

Comment: Sure, I would love to. I have some other functions too, where I try to get alliteration, and concreteness of each word, I would be glad to share them too, though they are sort of similar. Will notify! :)